# Bootstrap grid while loop

Tags: wp-query, loop, twitter-bootstrap

I made a grid with bootstrap where i want to show 5 differents posts but for some reason it duplicates the grids and shows one post per grid. [image: Here you can see how it starts to duplicate the grids]
[image: This is how i would like it to work]

First image shows how it starts to duplicate the grids 5 times instead of just showing 5 posts in those columns. Second picture shows how i would like to work.

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>


<main>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row"> <?php

$args = array(
<?php
'post_type' =>post_type' => 'post,
'posts_per_page' => 5,
);

$blogposts = new WP_Query($args);

while($blogposts->have_posts()) {
    $blogposts->the_post(); ?>



<div class="col-md-6">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>
        <div class="card border-0">
          <div class="card-picture">

            <img class="card-img" src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID()); ?>" alt="Card image">

            <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex flex-column">
              <h5 class="card-title font-weight-bold"><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
              <div class="mt-auto"> Miika - <i class="fas fa-clock"></i> 16.2.2020 - Oppaat</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <div class="card border-0">
          <div class="card-picture">

            <img class="card-img" src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID()); ?>" alt="Card image">

            <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex flex-column">
              <h5 class="card-title font-weight-bold"><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
              <div class="mt-auto">Miika - <i class="fas fa-clock"></i> 16.2.2020 - Oppaat</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

        <div class="card border-0">
          <div class="card-pic">

            <img class="card-img" src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID()); ?>" alt="Card image">

            <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex flex-column">
              <h3 class="card-title font-weight-bold"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
              <div class="mt-auto">Miika - <i class="fas fa-clock"></i> 16.2.2020 - Oppaat</div>

            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <div class="card border-0">
          <div class="card-pic">

            <img class="card-img" src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID()); ?>" alt="Card image">

            <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex flex-column">
              <h5 class="card-title font-weight-bold"><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
              <div class="mt-auto">Miika - <i class="fas fa-clock"></i> 16.2.2020 - Oppaat</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

        <div class="card border-0">
          <div class="card-pic">

            <img class="card-img" src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID()); ?>" alt="Card image">

            <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex flex-column">
              <h5 class="card-title font-weight-bold"><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
              <div class="mt-auto">Miika - <i class="fas fa-clock"></i> 16.2.2020 - Oppaat</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>

    <?php }
wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop means, "Every time I have one post, output the following code." Since you have 5 divs inside the `while` loop, you are getting 5 copies for each post. So, change your `while { }` code to this, which will output just 1 div for every post:

```
while($blogposts->have_posts()) {
    $blogposts->the_post(); ?>



<div class="col-md-6">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>
        <div class="card border-0">
          <div class="card-picture">

            <img class="card-img" src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID()); ?>" alt="Card image">

            <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex flex-column">
              <h5 class="card-title font-weight-bold"><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
              <div class="mt-auto"> Miika - <i class="fas fa-clock"></i> 16.2.2020 - Oppaat</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>


    <?php }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried that and yes its close the way i want. It shows 5 posts now but they are not in the grid how i want them to be. Ill post an picture.

Comment: You may need to adjust the markup to fit how Bootstrap holds the markup - for example, you might have to add a "row" wrapper around them all, outside the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
   while($blogposts->have_posts()) {
    $blogposts->the_post(); ?>



<div class="col-md-6">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>
        <div class="card border-0">
          <div class="card-picture">

            <img class="card-img" src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID()); ?>" alt="Card image">

            <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex flex-column">
              <h5 class="card-title font-weight-bold"><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
              <div class="mt-auto"> Miika - <i class="fas fa-clock"></i> 16.2.2020 - Oppaat</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>


    <?php }
```

Changing the while loop makes it show the 5 posts like i wanted but the posts are still not in the bootstrap columns.[image]Picture below shows what im trying to achieve. [image: This is what i am trying to achieve.]